# how could I define between two dates variable, that if you don't put any date manually, it shows the results of the last 24hrs?

Tags: postgresql, metabase

```
with all_data as (
  select  agent_id ,date(created_at) ,  , count(delivered)as number_of_orders 
  from orders_order
  where date(created_at) between {{start_date}} and {{end_date}}
  group by date,agent_id
  order by date
)
select ag.first_name, ag.last_name, ad.* 
from all_data as ad 
  left join agents_agent as ag on ad.agent_id=ag.id
```

Comment: 1) What is type for `created_at` field? 2) If you are working with dates only then you can only go back in date not hour increments. 3) How are you planning on populating the variables in `{{start_date}} and {{end_date}}`?  4) What is the value of variable if is not entered manually? **Add answers as update to question**

Comment: 1) the type of created_at is just yyyy/mm/dd 2)i don't want hours 3)i tried field filter but when i try to run the code it brings error and I don't know why 4)i want it to show the today's data by default, but if I wanted other days data, I can set the variables

Comment: **Add answers as update to question.** `yyyy/mm/dd` is a format not a data type. What is the data type as defined in the table? What did you try and what was the error message when it failed? **Again add answers as update to question.**